# Hadoop Text Object toString() Split Problems

Tags: java, hadoop

My hadoop mapper is emitting a csv line by line as a text object as follows:

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String dataRows[] = value.toString().trim().split("\\r?\\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int partition = r.nextInt(3);
        HC.set(Integer.toString(partition));
        Data.set(dataRows[i]);
        context.write(HC, Data);
    }
}
```

Within my reducer, I need to split the csv and use the strings for some further action. Here is the reducer code:

```
public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text data = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<Coord> coords = new ArrayList<Coord>();
        Iterator<Text> iter = values.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String[] elems = iter.next().toString().split(",");
            double[] x = new double[elems.length];
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i] = Integer.parseInt(elems[i]);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            }
            coords.add(new Coord(x));
        }
        try {
            Cluster cluster = runClusterer(coords);
            data.set(cluster.toNewick()+";");
            context.write(key, data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the strange thing, the elems string array has a length of 1 and contains only the left elements of every line of my CSV.

For e.g - Suppose my CSV contains two rows. First row - `{1,2}` and second row `{3,4}`

The elems array is getting populated as `{1,3}`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the value being emitted from.mapper.? For your input the mapper will.emit (random(1|2|3),{1,2} ) and (random(1|2|3),{3,4} )?

Comment: By any chance, did you use your reducer as combiner as well?

Comment: You can imagine if the random function is not there and I am giving a constant key. The problem persists.

Comment: No I didnt use my reducer as a combiner.

Comment: I can't seem to find a solution to this issue. The elems[] string array always contains one element.